# What counts as an “injured ally” for the spell Compassionate Ally?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, injury

For the spell [Compassionate Ally](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/compassionate-ally), it is clear this causes the target to run off to help one of their "injured" allies, (not the caster's allies, because why else would they still be able to attack as normal if out of healing options?).

However, what exactly counts as an “injured ally” for this spell? Is it just someone who isn't at full hit points? Or is it explicitly an unconscious/bleeding out ally?

Comment: Note that the tag [[tag:rules-as-written]] has a specific purpose, which is not just “questions about the rules”. Unless you're attempting to do something unusual with the rules, the tag doesn't apply. The correct tag for simply asking about the rules of the game is the one for the rules being asked about — in this case, [[tag:pathfinder]].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spell [***compassionate ally***](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/compassionate-ally) says, "At the sight of an injured ally, the target immediately disengages from its current course of action and rushes to provide aid," but later says that the creature affected by spell "refuses to leave the ally’s side until her *wounds* are fully treated or the spell ends…" (emphasis mine). Thus this GM would rule that to garner the attention of a creature affected by the spell *compassionate ally*, an ally's wound must be (*ahem*) bloody obvious.

For example, an ally that's below his maximum hp due to being dealt damage by a greatsword would, in most cases, have an obvious, visible wound. However, a creature that's been [deafened](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Deafened) due to the effect of a [thunderstone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/herbs-oils-other-substances#TOC-Thunderstone), suffering from a [temporary negative level](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Energy-Drain-and-Negative-Levels) due to a wight's [energy drain](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Energy-Drain-Su-), or been dealt Constitution [ability damage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores#TOC-Ability-Score-Damage) from the ingested [poison](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison) [arsenic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison/arsenic)—depending upon how the GM adjudicates each effect—just *may not have* a visible wound (despite meeting the traditional definition of *injured*); such an ally may not warrant the attention of a creature affected by the spell *compassionate ally*.

Note that the spell *compassionate ally* does *not* specify that an affected creature *only* tends wounds caused during the *current* encounter! For example, an ally suffering from an obvious, visible wound that was inflicted a week ago would still attract the attention of a creature affected by the spell *compassionate ally*.

***Note:*** The Pathfinder Roleplaying Game Core Rulebook *on [Injury and Death](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html) discusses the former* only *in the context of hp loss. Hence a strict GM may rule that an "injured ally" (as per the* compassionate ally *spell) is* exclusively *an ally that appears to have suffered hp loss. This seems a bit extreme to* this *GM, but ask your GM to make sure.*

Comment: I do like your outlook on the matter and the solid explination, however I will take your advice to ask our GM. Ill be sure to ask myself, my opinion on the matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Injured, in English, means:

> harmed, damaged, or impaired

In Pathfinder, this would include any reduction from (current) maximum hp as well as being poisoned, stunned, asleep, paralyzed etc. etc. That is, if the ally is in *any* way "harmed, damaged, or impaired" then the target will race off to help them and stay with them until they are not "harmed, damaged, or impaired" *even if there is nothing they **can** do to assist them*. That is the whole point of the spell.